# unresolved external symbol _ippiResize_8u_*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intel-ipp

My application needs the functions "ippiResize_8u_C1R @ 68" and "ippiResize_8u_C3R @ 68". These two methods are in the "AynxImage.lib" file, but the version of the ipp I use is 2015 and 2018 (ippi.h), how can I get the .lib file needed or renew I can adapt.
If I manually changed the words "ippiResize_8u_C1R @ 68" and "ippiResize_8u_C3R @ 68" in the "AynxImage.lib" file.I get the following compiler error

```
(compiler file 'f: \ dd \ vctools \ compiler \ utc \ src \ p2 \ p2symtab.c', line 2098)
```

[image]

Comment: Mixing libraries compiled with different versions of visual studio leads to a world of pain. Can you recompile this AynxImage library with your modern compiler?

Comment: When I use visual studio 2019 it looks like this.

C1047 The object or library file 'C: \ Users \ Aker \ Desktop \ 2.0 \ external \ lib \ release \ AynxDirectoryInfo.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries AyonixFaceID C: \ Users \ Aker \ Desktop \ 2.0 \ src \ AyonixFaceID \ LINK 1

Comment: Yes, so please recompile this aynx library with a modern compiler if that is possible.

Comment: How can I do that? Do you have a chance to explain step by step.

Comment: Get the source code, recompile with visual studio 2019. If you don't have source code, ask the vendor.

Comment: How can I compiler the corresponding "header" file?
Can you give me a link?

Comment: It cannot. You need source code to recompile.